# DAO + Webservice

Tags: java, web-service, eclipse, postgresql, padrão-dao

Quero utilizar o padrão DAO para criar um projeto em Java no Eclipse para visualizar os dados de um banco. Só que quero transformá-lo em uma Webservice.. Como devo proceder? Só basta utilizar aquela opção de criação de Webservice da IDE e pronto?

Comment: Você pode usar o padrão DAO tranquilamente em um `WebService`. No meu caso eu utilizo Vraptor, faço o projeto normalmente e apenas chamo o método que fica no DAO em meu controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, aparentemente sua dúvida é sobre a estrutura do projeto, certo?
Na IDE vc cria um projeto web dinâmico (Dynamic Web project), ela também te dá suporte a escolher as bibliotecas que vc precisará em seu projeto. Quanto ao pattern DAO, é um design de classes que vc usará para manipular o banco de dados.
A aconselho vc a estruturar seu projeto usando o MVC com DAO.

Comment: Então, posso escrever os métodos (Estabelecer conexão no banco e listar dados) numa classe só e depois gerar o Webservice?

Comment: claro, como o brother comentou acima, vc deve pensar em separação de camadas.
o DAO servirá apenas para fazer transações (CRUD) no banco de dados.
essas transações serão gerenciadas por um controlador(métodos que chamam os métodos do DAO) e enviará o resultado para sua camada de visualização (webservice). 

só uma dúvida, vc está utilizando que linguagem e que tecnologia de persistência?

Comment: Utilizando : Java, postgres e JDBC. Só quero algo simples que envolva RMI, isto é : Tenho que estabelecer conexão com o banco e listar dados do banco. Não quero utilizar frameworks, como Hibernate, pois tenho que terminar logo um trabalho, estou sem muito tempo e estou meio perdida.

Comment: Desculpe-me por essas perguntas meio chatas... Sou iniciante em Web services.

Comment: ahhh tá, sem broncas.

Comment: bom, neste caso sua dúvida é a questão a conexão com o banco?

Comment: Sim... Pois quero que o cliente que vá consumir o web service não tenha problemas ao estabelecer a conexão.

Comment: Bom, estão vc terá que dar uma estudada em Pool de conexões e datasource. Para isso vc deverá configurar seu Servidor de aplicações ou se for o caso web container, eu uso o servidor de app glassfish.
Isso fará com que o servidor de aplicações gerencie as conexões com a aplicação, neste caso vários clientes poderão estar conectados simultaneamente à sua aplicação. Bom, se é o que entendi da sua pergunta. :)  o que não tem muito a ver com DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve pensar em separação de camadas antes de mais nada.

Vamos pensar, o Pattern de DAO é um padrão para acesso ao banco de dados, ele é uma camada pra isso, não se deve imaginar ele com outra responsabilidade além dessa, isso é um conceito de [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Separando em camadas, devemos ter pelo menos mais uma pra implementar a camada de web services ou endpoint, devemos ter essa camada pra expor as suas funcionalidades ou dados.

Ou seja, DAO + Rest, DAO + SOAP, DAO + RTC e etc.

E uma dica, faça essa camada, não deixe que IDE ou outras ferramentas faça isso pra você, tente entender o que você está escrevendo e está tentando implementar.